# How to kill a process by port on MacOS, a la fuser -k 9000/tcp

Tags: macos, process, port, kill

On linux I can kill a process knowing only the port it is listening on using `fuser -k 9000/tcp`, how do I so the same on MacOS?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
lsof -P | grep ':PortNumber' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Change `PortNumber` to the actual port you want to search for.

Comment: I just had to add `-9` to the end to get this to work, but I believe that is due to the nature of the listening application and not generally recommended practice, to `kill -9` that is.

Comment: @Kris - lsof -P | grep ':NumberOfPort' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 worked!

Answer (score 24):

Adding the -t and -i flags to `lsof` should speed it up even more by removing the need for grep and awk.

```
lsof -nti:NumberOfPort | xargs kill -9
```

`lsof` arguments:

- `-n` Avoids host names lookup (may result in faster performance)
- `-t` Terse output; returns process IDs only to facilitate piping the output to kill
- `-i` Selects only those files whose Internet address matches

`kill` arguments:

- `-9` Non-catchable, non-ignorable kill

Comment: Works and is more concise than the accepted answer!

Comment: WAY faster with this approach

Answer (score 4):

You can see if a port if open by this command

```
 sudo lsof -i :8000
```

*where 8000 is the port number*

If the port is open, it should return a string containing the Process ID (PID).

Copy this PID and

```
kill -9 PID
```

If you need to see all the open ports, you can perform a Port Scan in the Network Utility application.

Answer (score 3):

Add -n to lsof and you remove the reverse DNS lookup from the command and reduce the run time from minutes to seconds.

```
lsof -Pn | grep ':NumberOfPort' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your port is open or not by

> sudo lsof -i : {PORT_NUMBER}

```
COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    582 Thirumal  300u  IPv6 0xf91b63da8f10f8b7      0t0  TCP *:distinct (LISTEN)
```

2. Close the port by killing process PID

```
sudo kill -9 582
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kill -9 $(lsof -i:PORT -t) 2> /dev/null`, where PORT is your actual port number. It will kill the process which is running on your given port.

Comment: You are repeating other answer

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to have tool with a GUI, you can use: https://github.com/ayedo/tcpkiller